# How can I make my vector update when passed in a function?

Tags: c++, vector

When I have this piece of code:

```
int push666 (vector<int> vect){

    vect.push_back(666);
}

int main()
{

    vector<int> a;
    a.reserve(1);
    push666(a);

    cout << a[0];

    return 0;
}
```

The cout will simply print out some garbage value. It seems like functions don't have a lasting effect on the vector. What can I do about it?

Comment: `push666` needs to take a `vector<int>&`, not a `vector<int>`. And you need to read a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/241631).

Comment: I am going to read one. Your list made it much easier for me, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pass the vector by reference instead of by value.

```
int push666 (vector<int>& vect){  
                    // ^^^  
    vect.push_back(666);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

C++ supports passing by *value* and by *reference*.

In your code, the `std::vector<int>` is passed to the function **by value** - it is copied and **this very copy** is modified and `std::vector<int>::push_back`ed.

In order to prevent the copy<sup>1</sup>, so the function directly operates on `a`, you need to **pass it by reference**:

```
int push666 (vector<int>& vect){
    vect.push_back(666);
}
```

The other way, the C way (or bad C++ way) is to pass a pointer:

```
int push666 (vector<int>* vect){
    vect->push_back(666);
}
```

Note that the pointer is passed **by value** here.

---

<sup>1</sup> The standard doesn't specify that but a reference is probably implemented with a pointer, so technically **some** copying **is** made.

Comment: It's "call by XXX", not "copy by XXX".

Answer (score 1):

You should pass it by reference:

```
int push666 (vector<int>& vect){

    vect.push_back(666);
}
```

or what is less common by pointer:

```
int push666 (vector<int>* vect){

    vect->push_back(666);
}
push666(&a); // use & to take address of a
```

both ways allows you to modify arguments passed to functions